# Issue with automatically starting app

Tags: android

I see this has been asked quite a bit, but I can't seem to resolve my problem with what is out there.

My `onReceive()` method in broadcast receiver isn't being called.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.test.TestActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

BootUpReceiver.java

```
package com.app.test;

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "TESTAPP_BootUpReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "helllllllllllllllo");
    Toast.makeText(context, "boot completed received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Intent i = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
    // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    // context.startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Have tried using the entire path instead of `.BootUpReceiver`, didn't work.  Not seeing anything from logcat or any Toast messages.  Going into `adb shell` and emitting the boot_completed event that way doesn't help as the device then reboots.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?  I read something about applications being inactive when device boots, does that affect my problem?

Comment: you dont need to give the permission again inside the <receiver>-tag. though on first sight, i don't see the difference between my working receover and yours. I'll watch closer now :)

Comment: tested it. the Toast is visible on Lockscreen, though the Log-message is not shown in my logs.

Comment: That's why the Toast is there - I read logging isn't up and running before event is sent.  I couldn't see it in lockscreen, maybe I'll try another device.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some reference in Android developer website
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

> Broadcast Receivers listening for "boot completed"
>   The system delivers the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast before the external storage is mounted to the device. If your application is installed on the external storage, it can never receive this broadcast.

Comment: Haven't supplied the `installLocation` in the manifest so it goes to internal by default.